# Send email using django without a settings file

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sendgrid

Is it possible to do something like the following using the utility django sendmail?

```
>>> import os
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> os.environ['EMAIL_BACKEND'] = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
>>> os.environ['EMAIL_HOST'] = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
... etc.
>>> send_mail(
...     'Subject here',
...     'Here is the message.',
...     'from@example.com',
...     ['to@example.com'],
...     fail_silently=False,
... )
```

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting EMAIL_BACKEND, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

If so, how could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Django without a `settings.py` file. As the error message states, you'll have to call `settings.configure()` to manually configure settings.

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.configure(EMAIL_HOST='smtp.sendgrid.net', other_settings...)
```

Pass the settings that you want to override to `configure()` function;  otherwise Django will use the default values.

---

See related docs for more: [Using settings without setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module).

Comment: thanks, never actually manually configured the `settings.configure` option but that's great. Thanks for the tip!